# Wicket - how to refresh single row in a table with ajax

Tags: java, wicket

In my wicket application I have a table where each column of a row described by one bean. One of the column contains an ajax component that can change the values in the bean and therefore the values displayed in other columns.

How can I update these columns without reloading the whole table?

Now I use the following code:

```
public static <T> void refreshTableRow(AjaxRequestTarget target, Item<ICellPopulator<T>> columnItem) { 
    for (Component component : columnItem.getParent()) {
        if (component instanceof Item) {
            ((Item<?>) component).stream()
                    .filter(Component::getOutputMarkupId)
                    .forEach(target::add);
        }
    }
}
```

But for the proper work of this code I have to set `outputMarkupId(true)` for the root component of each column, created in `IColumn#populateItem`.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Which component do you use for the table ? DataTable ?!

Comment: Yes, I use DataTable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `DataTable#newRowItem()` and return some custom Item implementation that has `outputMarkupId = true`.

```
public class MyRow<T> extends Item<T> {
   public MyRow<T>(String id, int index, IModel<T> model) {
     super(id, index, model);

     setOutputMarkupId(true);
   }
}
```

Then in your Ajax callback method do:

```
ajaxRequestTarget.add(findParent(MyRow.class));
```

Comment: OMG - your suggestion works really well. I shudder when thinking of how I used to force a row to get updated - typically ended up refreshing the whole table view :(
As the need to update an individual rows is so common in our app I've actually created a new class derived (indirectly) from DataTable that will always create rows that have outputMarkupId set to true - so I now instantiate that type instead and so individual row updates are now a piece of cake.